# Cropping/Trimming an image with includegraphics by specifying percentages

Tags: graphics, adjustbox

Say I have an image `my_image.png` that I am loading in my LaTeX document using:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{my_image.png}}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way of telling LaTeX to only render a specific rectangular portion (in **percentages**) of the original image?

For example, say I want to just render a cropped image:

- Trim `5%` of the original image **width** from the **left**
- Trim `10%` of the original image **width** from the **right**
- Trim `15%` of the original image **height** from the **top**
- Trim `20%` of the original image **height** from the **bottom**

Comment: have a look at the package `adjustbox` with the option `export`.

Comment: Note that all clipping (or cropping) is done by telling the document viewer not to display these parts. The whole image is still be stored in the output file and might be extracted by readers with more advanced software. So it is not recommended to use this technique to hide secret parts of the image. In such cases the image should be cropped manually beforehand by an external tool.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\adjustbox{trim={.05\width} {.2\height} {0.1\width} {.15\height},clip}%
  {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{cupdot.png}}

\end{document}
```

Since `\includegraphics` produces no depth, you can use the fact that `\adjustbox` knows the `\width` and the `\height` of the image.

Comment: Can be written a little shorter with newer versions of `adjustbox`:  `\adjincludegraphics[width=0.5cm,Clip={.05\width} {.2\height} {0.1\width} {.15\height}]{cupdot.png}` (note the uppercase `Clip`).