# Could not insert pdf graphics

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdf

Using `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mypdf}` I tried to insert a PDF image to my XeLaTeX document. But instead of the images empty area places in its place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I got following in console:

```
** WARNING ** Multiple DecodeFilter not supported.
** WARNING ** Could not handle a content stream.
** WARNING ** pdf: image inclusion failed for "./my.pdf".
 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

What may be wrong? What kind of PDFs can be inserted in tex files?

Comment: How did you generate `my.pdf`? Perhaps you should convert it to PS and then convert back to PDF (see [XeTeX cannot include PDF page](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-January/015529.html)).

Comment: @Werner I generated pdf from yEd program. I don't have `pdf2ps` in my texlive dict.

Comment: @PHPst: Use `pdftops` instead, not `pdf2ps`.

Comment: @Werner It solved the issue and the output is far better that pdf2ps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a result of multiple decoders within the original PDF (as the message clearly states). [A solution](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-January/015529.html) is to convert the PDF to PostScript and then back again to PDF, which should encode it using a single decoder.

For this you would need [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) and perhaps [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) (which provides `pdftops`, if `pdf2ps` is not available). The conversion back to PDF should come standard with your TeX distribution in the form of [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf).

If this conversions results in a larger PDF than the original, you might consider running the intermediate PS through [`ps2ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps2ps) first, before converting back to PDF.

In summary:

```
pdftops  foo.pdf 
epstopdf foo.ps 
pdfcrop  foo.pdf
```

Comment: `pdftops` is distributed by TeXlive and porvides far better result that `pdf2ps'.

Comment: my original PDF file just includes a vector images, after converting resulting PDF contains a full A4 page that contains the images, is there any option prevent changing page size?

Comment: @PHPst: You can use [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) to trim your final PDF to the size of the resulting graphic.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[width=\linewidth]{my.pdf}
\end{document}
```

for multiple pages, or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=<pageNo>]{my.pdf}
\end{document}
```

for a single page

Comment: Is figure file extension mandatory ?

Comment: no, i copied it only from the mwe

Comment: I have no problem. Did you tried it with `page=1` and are you sure that the included document is in your path?

Comment: for example: http://texnik.dante.de/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news10.pdf

Comment: @PHPst: can you provide your pdf for a test?

Answer (score -1):

I have found a possible solution from

[Cropping/Trimming an image with includegraphics by specifying percentages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52695/cropping-trimming-an-image-with-includegraphics-by-specifying-percentages)

Trying the following TeX code:

```
\adjustbox{trim=5cm 5cm 5cm 5cm, clip}{\includegraphics[page=2]{source.pdf}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While the advice is sound for different kinds of problems, I don't see how it handles the present one.