# How does xelatex change an image

Tags: graphics, xetex, copyright

I have a particular logo image saved as a `pdf` file that I can include fine with `pdflatex`, but when I compile with `xelatex` the compilation fails. I think the issue is essentially the same as in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106964/could-not-insert-pdf-graphics), although my error message is different, and the answer to that question solves my `LaTeX` problem. Specifically, if I process `logo.pdf` with `pdftops/epstopdf`

```
pdftops logo.pdf
epstopdf logo.ps
```

and then run `xelatex` everything compiles fine.

Consider the following MWE `tex` file (`logo.tex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{logo.pdf}
\end{document}
```

and processing chain

```
pdftops logo.pdf
epstopdf logo.ps
xelatex logo.tex
```

How does the resulting `logo.pdf` differ from the original `logo.pdf`? I am curious about the effects of both `pdftops/epstopdf` and `xelatex` as well as if `pdflatex` was used instead.

The question is loosely motivated by my desire to decide if using the above processing chain would violate the spirit of licenses like [CC BY-ND](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/). I hope by understanding the differences, I can make a less uninformed decision.

Comment: Specifically it's more a question of `pdftops` and `epstopdf`.

Comment: @Toscho part of it is, but I am also interested in how `xelatex/pdflatex` would change the `pdf` produced by `epstopdf`.

Comment: You're not distributing the logo, just using it. The license says “Share — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format for any purpose, even commercially.” so I don't think there's any problem. But this is off-topic.