# Trimming images

Tags: graphics

Just a quick question, do you all trim the images by trail and error and plugging numbers there?? Do you use a mark or something to at least keep some reference?

well that's how I do it and is really painful.

Comment: are you asking about cropping off actual portions of an image, or simply reducing the size of the image to the correct bounding box?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to crop off parts of an image. Actually how you guys play to find the right Xs

`\includegraphics[trim = X X X X, clip,height=5]{imageName}`

Comment: Cropping images first with external tools and then including them as is in a document seems to be the smartest way for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For PDFs you should take a look at [`pdfcrop`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop). With this tool, you can crop away all the white parts around the figure. Alternatively you may try the [tool with the same name](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) which is not included in your TeX-distro but easy to use as well.

For custom cropping of PDFs I am using Adobe Standard (commercial software) or I crop it with `trim=..., clip`. If you are fit in Adobe or EPS/PS-tools like ghostscript/ghostviewer, you could manipulate the bounding box of your graphics to your needs. For EPS this can be done in an editor, too. You should know, what you are doing...

Raster-graphics like PNG and JPG can be cropped easily wit [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) or any other photo editing software. It is always the easiest, to crop as good as possible before inserting to your document. If you are working with screen-shots, you should take some tool to find an already cropped area of the screen. E.g. custom rectangle screen shot of [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.de/).

Vector graphics should be treated in software like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/?lang=de).

If you have to crop manually, you may want to superpose a help-grid like shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/32245). This gives you the possibility to have an easier orientation. But it's still a trial and error. (see Werners answer for easy percentage cropping with that grid)

Answer (score 10):

You can use a combination of [Drawing a grid on each image inside the array of images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113463/5764) and [Cropping/Trimming an image with `\includegraphics` by specifying percentages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52695/5764) you can

1. Draw the image you're interested in including with a grid overlay (showing percentages); and
2. Trim according to the percentages you're after.

This requires [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) (which loads [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) internally):
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{adjustbox,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand\imagegrid[1]{% Grid over image
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (A) {#1};
  \begin{scope}[x={(A.south east)},y={(A.north west)}]
  \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10} { \node [anchor=north,font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt] at (\x/10,0) {\x}; }
  \foreach \y in {0,1,...,10} { \node [anchor=east,font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt] at (0,\y/10) {\y}; }
  \end{scope}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\imagegrid{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}%

\adjustbox{trim={.35\width} {.25\height} {.35\width} {.25\height},clip}{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can make the grid finer for more precise measurement & trimming. The default clipping of images via `\includegraphics`'s `trim` key-value takes input as `b`ig `p`oints (or `bp`s).